google one-tap javascript origin for a site hosted at infinityfree
I have added my domain as well as the site name in Javascript origins, but I get the 403 forbidden error whenever I open google one-tap by javascript code.
Is it feasible for infinityfree site?
this is my code
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.accounts.id.initialize({
 client_id: '***************',
 callback: handleCredentialResponse
 });
 google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
     console.log('notification:', notification);
     if (notification.isNotDisplayed() || notification.isSkippedMoment()) {
         // try next provider if OneTap is not displayed or skipped
     }
 });
</script>

This is my error


